# pgsql: filter column to get latest value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have below query to pivot, how to get `status` value filtered on latest `updated_on` row for each `obj_key`

```
select obj_key, max(updated_on) as updated_on, max(att.status) as status,
  COALESCE(max(array_to_string(v_date,'||'::text)) filter (where att.type_key=1),(select default_value from types where type_key=1))  as "DOB",
  COALESCE(max(array_to_string(v_text,'||'::text)) filter (where att.type_key=2),(select default_value from types where type_key=2)) as "First Name",
  COALESCE(max(array_to_string(v_text,'||'::text)) filter (where att.type_key=3),(select default_value from types where type_key=3))as "Last Name",
  COALESCE(max(array_to_string(v_number,'||'::text)) filter (where att.type_key=4),(select default_value from types where type_key=4)) as "Contact"
  from attributes att right join types ty on att.type_key=ty.type_key
  group by obj_key
```

Table/data is here [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=632334a261fc5838612ce03414963aef)

i was trying by `first_value(status) OVER( ORDER BY updated_on) AS status`  but no luck

Can we get status as per max(updated_on) for each obj_key ?

Comment: I suggest you use something like `row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY obj_key ORDER BY updated_on DESC)` on your original dataset, BEFORE you do the conditional agg, so that essentially your data only contains the latest rows you're insterested in (so MAX has only one value to select, and cannot hence mix stuff up)

Comment: Not sure why your EAV pivot ignores `updated_on` for attribute values. What is PK of `attributes` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this version, the first_value(status) is changed to last_value(status) and the OVER W has been moved to the aggregate, so inside of the COALESCE statements.

```
select DISTINCT ON (obj_key) 
   obj_key, updated_on, 
   last_value(status) OVER w AS created_by,
   COALESCE(max(array_to_string(v_date,'||'::text)) filter (where 
   att.type_key=1) OVER w ,(select default_value from types where 
   type_key=1))  as "DOB",
   COALESCE(max(array_to_string(v_text,'||'::text)) filter (where 
   att.type_key=2) OVER w ,(select default_value from types where 
   type_key=2))  as "First Name",
   COALESCE(max(array_to_string(v_text,'||'::text)) filter (where 
   att.type_key=3) OVER w ,(select default_value from types where 
   type_key=3)) as "Last Name",
   COALESCE(max(array_to_string(v_number,'||'::text)) filter (where 
   att.type_key=4) OVER w ,(select default_value from types where 
   type_key=4)) as "Contact"
   from attributes att right join types ty on att.type_key=ty.type_key
   WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY obj_key ORDER BY updated_on)
   ORDER  BY obj_key, updated_on DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `PARTITION BY` for your window function. Since you want the first value for each `obj_key` you need:

```
first_value(status) OVER(PARTITION BY obj_key ORDER BY updated_on)
```

Comment: Added ```PARTITION BY``` still getting error ```column "att.status" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function```

Answer (score 0):

Provided PK of `attributes` is `(obj_key, type_key)` you only need to add `row_number()`  over all type_key's of obj_key.

```
select obj_key, max(updated_on) updated_on,
      max(case when rno = 1 then status end) as status, 
      max(array_to_string(v_date,'||'::text)) filter (where type_key=1) as "DOB",
      max(array_to_string(v_text,'||'::text)) filter (where type_key=2) as "First Name",
      max(array_to_string(v_text,'||'::text)) filter (where type_key=3) as "Last Name",
      max(array_to_string(v_number,'||'::text)) filter (where type_key=4) as "Contact"
from (
  select *, 
    row_number() over(partition by obj_key order by updated_on desc) rno
  from attributes) t
group by obj_key
```

**EDIT**
For perfomance reasons you can also use this old pre-windows-functions trick

```
select obj_key, max(updated_on) updated_on,
      substring(max(updated_on::text || status), 20, 100) as status, 
      max(array_to_string(v_date,'||'::text)) filter (where type_key=1) as "DOB",
      max(array_to_string(v_text,'||'::text)) filter (where type_key=2) as "First Name",
      max(array_to_string(v_text,'||'::text)) filter (where type_key=3) as "Last Name",
      max(array_to_string(v_number,'||'::text)) filter (where type_key=4) as "Contact"
from  attributes t
group by obj_key;
```

Comment: i'm afraid to write this ```select *, 
    row_number() over(partition by obj_key order by updated_on desc) rno
  from attributes```as subquery  as attributes table has more than 10 million records , it will impact performance doing group by twice on ```obj_key ```